# Crawl to final URL from within Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of domain names, and many of them redirect me to the same domain.  For instance... foo1.com, foo2.csm and foo3.com all deposit me at foo.com.

I'm trying to deduplicate the list of domains by writing a VBA script to load the final page and extract it's URL.

I've started from this article which retrieve's the page's title (http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/355192-can-i-import-raw-html-source-code-into-excel.html), but can't figure out how to modify it to get the final URL (from which I can extract the URL.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you provide an example of one the URL's you need to de-dupe?  Exactly how the redirection occurs could alter the possible answers.

Comment: Tim, the list is massive so no one example is representative.  Buy here's one example... adhpn2.com.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to "Microsoft XML, v3.0" (or whatever version you have)

```
Sub tester()
    Debug.Print CheckRedirect("adhpn2.com")
End Sub

Function CheckRedirect(URL As String)
    If Not UCase(URL) Like "HTTP://*" Then URL = "http://" & URL
    With New msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP40
        .Open "HEAD", URL, False
        .send
        CheckRedirect = .getOption(-1)
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, need to look at .LocationURL:

```
Public Function gsGetFinalURL(rsURL As String) As String
Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie
    .navigate rsURL
    Do While .Busy And Not .ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    gsGetFinalURL = .LocationURL
    .Quit
End With

Set ie = Nothing
End Function
```

I haven't tried it on a huge variety of URLs, just the one you gave and a couple of others. If it is an invalid URL it will return what is passed. You can use the code from the original function to check and handle accordingly.